# CentOS 7 startup error - unregistered net_device

Tags: linux-networking, centos7, startup

I see these errors upon startup of my CentOS 7 server. It has a Solarflare SFN8542 adapter. How can I fix this? I am pretty new to Linux.

[image: Startup Errors]

Answer (score 0):

This error message seems to indicate that this card requires 57 interrupts to function at its greatest performance.

This is *probably* related to the PCI bus installed on the mainboard. In particular its likely a older PCI 2.0 mainboard that doesn't support MSI-X.

MSI in particular only supports 32 vectors, MSI-X goes up to 2048.

Unless you plan on getting the full 40GiB out of that card, its probably not a problem.

Theres lots of useful information here: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/PCI/msi-howto.html

Comment: I believe the motherboard is definitely PCIe 3.0. This server is only a year old.

Comment: I got rid of the errors by issuing this command `sfboot -i [adapter] msix-limit=64` - I am hopeful this won't break anything